# jQuery/Javascript timepicker for separate inputs HH/mm

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have two input fields, one for hours and one for minutes, looks like this:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="HH" name="time_range_hour_from" value="<?=$time_range_hour_from?>" min="0" max="23" style="width: 70px;" /> : <input type="number" placeholder="mm" name="time_range_minute_from" value="<?=$time_range_minute_from?>" min="0" max="59" size="2"  style="width: 70px;" />
```

This works fine, but not very user friendly. What I want is something like this https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Time-Selection-Popover-jQuery-Timepicker.html
But everyone I have found only seems to support one input field.
Is it possible to use this kind of timepicker and save the hours and minutes into separate PHP variables like it works now?

Comment: Please make a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) of your code. So anyone can easily help you with your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the solutions that use only one input for it on the JS side and then split it on PHP side into hours and minutes.

So basically after you get the hours as a string like "12:34" you can use PHP's [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to split like

```
$time = "12:34"; //Value from your single input
$hour = substr($time, 0, 2);
$time = substr($time, 3, 5);
```